# Getting a relationship with a condition?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have category and article tables, they are in a many to many relationship. i have the relationships set up on the models.

How can I get all articles where a category id is = 1?

I've tried:

```
Article::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('category_id', $id);
    })->get();
```

The above works, but seems clunky, is there a more efficient way in eloquent to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use eager loading technique.

```
Article::with(['category', function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('category_id', $id);
    }])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following groupBy code is assuming that `Category::find($id)->articles` is not an option for whatever reason.

What about groupBy?

```
Article::groupBy('category')
          ->having('category', $id)
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`whereHas` will return articles that match that condition, but won’t filter articles then fetched by the same conditions. You could therefore create an anonymous function that contains the constraints, and pass it to *both* the `whereHas` and `with` methods:

```php
$filter = function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
    $query->where('category_id', '=', $categoryId);
};

Article::whereHas('category', $filter)
       ->with(['category' => $filter])
       ->get();
```